# Compressing a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Consider the system of linear equations $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ in which $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m < n$ and with the following property:

> **Property $\Gamma$**: Given $M=\{ M_1,\cdots,M_r \}$ where $M_i \subset \{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $0 < |M_i| < m$ for all $i$, the submatrix shaped by selecting columns $M_i$ from $A$ has full rank.

Property $\Gamma$ states that if person $i$ has all the variables, but is missing $\{ x_j | j \in M_i \}$, he can find the value of the missing variables by removing the values that he has from the system and solving the remaining ones.

However, the system $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has too many rows. It has $m$ rows but $k=\max_i |M_i|$ is enough for the system to have property $\Gamma$.

**Question:** Given $A$, $\mathbf b$, and $M$, is that possible to create a system $A'\mathbf x=\mathbf b'$ with $k$ rows and the same number of variables that preserves property $\Gamma$? How?

All the computation is done over a finite field GF$(p^q)$.

Comment: do you know the rank of $A$?

Comment: It is at least $k$ and at most $m$. But given $A$, the exact rank can be computed. How does it help?

Comment: I mean rank of $A$ is at least $k=\max_i |M_i|$. I made a mistake and used $k$ for two different purposes in my question, but it's know fixed.

Comment: Is there some sort of assumption on $\boldsymbol{x}$? If I understand correctly, since $A$ is a fat matrix, you can't generally solve the linear equation. I'm guessing you're assuming that $\boldsymbol{x}$ is sparse (i.e., it has at most $s$ nonzero elements for some fixed small integer $s$). If this is the case, what you asked sounds the same as or closely related to MDS codes or the separating distance of $A$.

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara: yes, $\mathbf x$ is sparse. And you are right, it's kind of similar to MDS codes, but not exactly. If $M$ contains all the subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ of size $k$, then it would be like MDS. It has a looser assumption.

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara: I guess I misunderstood your "$\mathbf x$ is sparse" statement. $\mathbf x$ is not sparse actually. You can assume that all $\mathbf x$ are non-zero. But $p^q$ is much larger than $n$. It means that only a few values of the finite field is used. But my explanation about MDS codes is correct. The system explained in my question cannot be solved in general. It can only be solved if someone knows the values of all but a few of the variables. It is the same with MDS codes: the system is solvable if one is missing at most $k$ variables.

Comment: @Mohsen Oh, I missed your comments before posting the "answer" that is actually a long comment. But I guess I made it clear exactly what you mean. I hope it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got what you mean. Please correct me if I misunderstand your question.

So, I think "$0 < \vert M_i\vert < m$" in the description of property $\Gamma$ should read "$0 < \vert M_i\vert \leq k$." And what the paragraph under the description says is that

1. some entires of $\boldsymbol{x}$ are constants rather than variables, and
2. which entries are constants is determined by which $M_i$ is chosen from $M$, i.e., the values of the "variables" that do not correspond to the columns of chosen $M_i$ will be assumed to be known a priori.

So, what you want to do is, given a family $M$ of subsets $M_i \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $\vert M_i\vert <k$, find a submatrix $A'$ that consists of $k$ rows of $A$ such that for any $M_i$ the $k \times \vert M_i\vert$ submatrix of $A'$ that consists of the columns specified by $M_i$ is full rank.

In general, it seems very unlikely that there exists a polynomial time algorithm that determines whether desirable $A'$ exists. This is because what you're asking is to determine if the linear code defined by $A$ as its parity-check matrix can detect all errors that correspond to $M_i$.

Take $M_x\in M$. Let $\boldsymbol{e}=(e_0,\dots,e_{n-1})$ be the $n$-dimensional vector such that $e_i=1$ if $i\in M_x$ and otherwise zero. Assuming $\vert M_x\vert < \frac{n}{2}$, a linear code defined by $H$ can correct error $\boldsymbol{e}$ if and only if

1. $H'$ that corresponds to columns specified by $M_x$ is full rank and
2. $H'$ with any other set of $\vert M_x\vert$ columns (which are not in $H'$) is also full rank.

So, if $M$ contains all subsets of size $t$, to have a desired submatrix you want, the linear code defined by $A$ should be of minimum distance at least $\frac{t-1}{2}$.

It is known that determining the minimum distance of a linear code is NP-complete. Moreover, it is proved that the minimum distance of a linear code is not approximable to within any constant factor in random polynomial time, unless NP equals random polynomial time:

[I. Dumer, D. Micciancio, M. Sudan, Hardness of Approximating the minimum
distance of a linear code, *IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory,* **49** (2003), 22-37](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2002.806118) (available for free [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/papers/DMS.pdf)).

But you should know if $d\geq\frac{t-1}{2}$. Now you didn't specify how $M$ is chosen. But, for example, assume that you may end up with $M$ with all subsets of size $c\cdot n$ for some constant $c$. In other words, your algorithm should determine if $d\geq c'\cdot n$ for some constant $c'$. Because the minimum distance of a random linear code satisfies the Gilbert-Varshamov bound with high probability (which was proved in [J. Pierce, Limit distribution of the minimum distance of random linear codes, IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory, **13** (1967), 595-599](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1967.1054053)), basically your algorithm should determine if $d\geq c''\cdot d$ for some constant $c''$, which seems unlikely to be in polynomial time.

Comment: I correct #2: $M_i$ specifies the unknown variables, not the known ones.

Comment: @Mohsen Oh, I forgot to put "do not" before "correspond." This is what you meant, I think?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Thanks :)

Comment: I like to add: $A'$ does not simply consist of $k$ rows of $A$. Each row of $A'$ can be a linear combination of all of rows of $A$. Since $A$ is $m\times n$ and $A'$ is $k\times n$, the question can be seen as finding a conversion matrix $T_{k\times m}$ such $A'=TA$.

Comment: I think if $M$ contains only a few $M_i$, a random matrix $T$ solves the problem with high probability, but as $|M|$ grows, a random assignment to $T$ becomes less probable to solve the problem.

Comment: @Mohsen About $A'$ might be $TA$: But that doesn't change the situation, does it? Your definition of $\Gamma$ seems to say that $A'$ should be rows of $A$.

Comment: @Mohsen Anyway, I revised this long comment to make it an answer. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Mohsen The randomized approach doesn't work that well. It's not in random polynomial time. See the edit of the answer.

Comment: I think the paper you referenced is an interesting one, but I cannot see the relation between inapproximability of $d$ and my question. Assume $M$ contains all the subsets of size $t$. Then, if I am not mistaken, my question is: Given a $[n+m, n, k]$ ECC, find a $[n+k, n, k]$ which is MDS, right? And they are both systematic ECCs.

Comment: @Mohsen A parity-check matrix $H$ doesn't have to be systematic. Take $M_x\in M$. Let $\boldsymbol{e}=(e_0,\dots,e_{n-1})$ be the $n$-dimensional vector such that $e_i=1$ if $i\in M_x$ and otherwise zero. A linear code defined by $H$ can correct error $\boldsymbol{e}$ if and only if (1) $H'$ that corresponds to columns specified by $M_x$ is full rank and (2) $H'$ with any other set of $\vert M_x\vert$ columns (which are not in $H'$) is also full rank. So, if $M$ contains all subsets of size $t$, the linear code should be of minimum distance at least $\frac{t-1}{2}$.

Comment: So you should know if $d\geq\frac{t-1}{2}$. Now you didn't specify how $M$ is chosen. But, for example, assume that you may end up with $M$ with all subsets of size $c\cdot n$ for some constant $c$. In other words, your algorithm should determine if $d\geq c'\cdot n$ for some constant $c'$. Because the minimum distance of a random linear code satisfies the Gilbert-Varshamov bound with high probability, basically your algorithm should determine if $d\geq c''\cdot d$ for some constant $c''$, which seems unlikely to be in polynomial time.

Comment: $M$ is a feature of the system that I am designing and I have no control over it, but it can be anything. I also have some constraints for $A$. That's why $A$ is not as compact as possible. Anyways, for a given $M$, I construct $A$ in such a way that it has the desired property $\Gamma$; thus $d\ge\frac{t-1}{2}$ for $A$. But later, I want to compress it to $A'$. $A$ is not a random matrix.

Comment: I think $A'=TA$ for a random matrix $T$ is not a uniformly distributed random matrix over GF$(p^q)^{k\times n}$ since it's rows are linear combinations of rows of $A$. That's why I think the result of the paper doesn't apply to my problem.

Comment: @Mohsen Well, if $A$ is not even remotely random, my informal argument doesn't work. Sorry, but I can't know assumptions on $A$ because you didn't tell me. The question you wrote makes it sound like $A$ is taken randomly... Besides, you didn't tell whatever constrains on A you have in mind when I said you might want to impose restrictions on something. So, I guess I have to give up now because I don't know exactly what problem you want to solve...

Comment: Thanks Yuichiro. Actually, construction of $A$ is quite complicated and too long to be described here (I am still writing it down and it's already 3 pages). But I think it's not relevant as long as $A$ has the property $\Gamma$. Anyways, thanks for your time and effort. I learned a lot from our discussion. I'll write the answer here if I found it.

Comment: @Mohsen Ah, I think I now understand where I misread your question. $A$ is a priori known to satisfy $\Gamma$? I was thinking it was unknown a priori! Sorry if I wasted your time... Anyway, Good luck!